# Meteor Method return value not reflecting on cliend side

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I have written a Meteor.call() method to check if the user already exists in the system.

Below is the code

**views/clientside.js**

```
  inviteEmail() {
  let inviteEmailAddress = FlowRouter.getParam("inviteEmail");
    var emailExist = false;
    if (inviteEmailAddress !== "") {
       Meteor.apply("v1/checkIfEmailExists", { inviteEmailAddress },  { wait :true  }, (e, r ) => {
        if (e) {
          Meteor.Error(404, "Error checking the email ");
        } else {
          if (r) {
            console.log(inviteEmailAddress + " result found ", r);
            emailExist = true;
          } else {
            console.log(inviteEmailAddress + " result not found ", r);
          }
        }
      });
```

**imports/api/methods.js**

```
export const checkIfEmailExists = new ValidatedMethod({
    name: 'v1/checkIfEmailExists',
    validate: new SimpleSchema({
        inviteEmailAddress: { type: String },
    }).validator(),
    run({ inviteEmailAddress }) {
        console.log("received ", inviteEmailAddress ) ; 
       console.log(Accounts.findUserByEmail(inviteEmailAddress)) ;

        return Meteor.isServer && Accounts.findUserByEmail(inviteEmailAddress)
        // return Meteor.users.find({ _id: { $in: users } }, { fields: { profile: 1, info: 1, emails: 1 } }).fetch();
    },
});
```

Below is the exception details:

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'v1/checkIfEmailExists' Error: The first argument of validate() or validateOne() must be an object
    at doValidation1 (aldeed_simple-schema.js:2284)
    at doValidation (aldeed_simple-schema.js:2920)
    at SimpleSchemaValidationContext.simpleSchemaValidationContextValidate [as validate] (aldeed_simple-schema.js:2955)
    at SimpleSchema.validate (aldeed_simple-schema.js:2138)
    at MethodInvocation.<anonymous> (aldeed_simple-schema.js:2164)
    at ValidatedMethod._execute (mdg_validated-method.js:131)
    at MethodInvocation.v1/checkIfEmailExists (mdg_validated-method.js:99)
    at ddp-client.js:976
    at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (meteor.js:1207)
    at Connection.apply (ddp-client.js:967)
```

My issue is client is rendering always false even though the user is available in the database. So essentially the return value is not at all reflecting on the client side data.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

`Meteor.apply`'s second argument is an Array of arguments, similar to `function.prototype.apply`

```
Meteor.apply("v1/checkIfEmailExists", [{ inviteEmailAddress }],  { wait :true  }, (e, r ) => {
```

https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-apply

Were you getting any errors on the server or client?

---

EDIT: You're getting errors about `Accounts.findUserByEmail` because it's a server only method, which I assume you knew because you in your return line you put it behind a server check.
You're now getting the error because of the console.log line calling the method

Comment: Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'v1/checkIfEmailExists' TypeError: Accounts.findUserByEmail is not a function
    at MethodInvocation.run (app.js:68377)
    at ValidatedMethod._execute (mdg_validated-method.js:137)
    at MethodInvocation.v1/checkIfEmailExists (mdg_validated-method.js:99)
    at ddp-client.js:976
    at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (meteor.js:1207)
    at Connection.apply (ddp-client.js:967)
    at Object.inviteEmail (app.js:16970)
    at blaze.js:2850
    at blaze.js:1566
    at blaze.js:2903

Comment: Hi #Fred, I am facing the above exception. Actually I am receiving the output from the server but the received value not reflecting. Some synchronisation issue it seems.

Comment: can you edit that into the original question? That's pretty crucial information. I'll edit my answer in a sec

Comment: Hi @Fred , I have edited the question, and removed comments from the server side code. Now I am getting a new exception as edited above.

Comment: Hi @Fred, I have changed the var emailExist as ReactiveVar and now Return value is now reflecting. I am able to validate my method now. Thanks for your support.